# How to create new commands in Zuul CI to trigger custom jobs

Tags: zuul-ci

Similar to `recheck` command, if I want to create custom trigger commands in Zuul CI, what's the best possible way to implement it?

For example, I want to have following 2 commands defined in Zuul to trigger specific tests.

`/test-e2e` - This would trigger a specific job that runs e2e tests

`/test-conformance` - This would trigger a specific job that triggers conformance tests.

Can somebody please advise?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using GitHub to manage you source code you could define a custom regex trigger for you check pipeline

See [documentation](https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/reference/drivers/github.html) of `pipeline.trigger.<github source>.comment`

Something like this:

```
- pipeline:
    name: check
    trigger:
      github:
        - event: pull_request
          action: comment
          comment: (?i)^\s*test-e2e\s*$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using `experimental` pipeline in Zuul.